# Miller-Rabin Prime test (Speed is the main goal)

Tags: java, performance, primes

The code below is for testing Primes.

```
testPrime(100000);
testPrime(1000000);
testPrime(10000000);
testPrime(100000000);
```

Now my goal is to make the code super fast at finding prime number, min-max, close prime.
Are there any improvements that can be done to the code below to improve the speed for `IsPrime`?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.math.*;


class Primes {


    private static long[] as = {2, 7, 61};

    private static long modpow(long x, long c, long m) {
        long result = 1;
        long aktpot = x;
        while (c > 0) {
            if (c % 2 == 1) {
                result = (result * aktpot) % m;
            }
            aktpot = (aktpot * aktpot) % m; 
            c /= 2;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean millerRabin(long n) {
        outer:
        for (long a : as) {
            if (a < n) {
                long s = 0;
                long d = n - 1;
                while (d % 2 == 0) {
                    s++;
                    d /= 2;
                }

                long x = modpow(a, d, n);
                if (x != 1 && x != n - 1) {
                    for (long r = 1; r < s; r++) {
                        x = (x * x) % n;
                        if (x == 1) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (x == n - 1) {
                            continue outer;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static boolean IsPrime(long num) {
        if (num <= 1) {
            return false;
        } else if (num <= 3) {
            return true;
        } else if (num % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return millerRabin(num);
        }
    }
    public static int[] primes(int min, int max) {
           ArrayList<Integer> primesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

           for( int i=min; i<max; i++ ){
                if( IsPrime(i) ){
                   primesList.add(i);
                }
           }

           int[] primesArray = new int[primesList.size()];
           for(int i=0; i<primesArray.length; i++){
               primesArray[i] = (int) primesList.get(i);
           }

           return primesArray;
        }


    public static String tostring (int [] arr){
        String ans="";
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
            ans= ans+arr[i]+ " ";
        }
        return ans;
    }
     public static int closestPrime(int num) {
            int count=1;    
            for (int i=num;;i++){

                int plus=num+count, minus=num-count;
                if (IsPrime(minus)){

                    return minus;

                }

                if (IsPrime(plus)) {
                    return plus;

                }
                count=count+1;
            }
        }


    }   

//end class
```

Comment: Profile it and look where you spent most of the time. I would expect the modpow function., which is not that easy to further optimize.

Comment: perhaps  `if (a < n) { continue;}` is better no jump to end of if statement before going to loop, but it would depends on compiler clerverness

Comment: Is `c % 2 == 1` in Java guaranteed to optimize down to the same as `c & 1 == 0`? The reason I ask is because the type of `c` is `long`, which is *signed*, so this might force the JVM to use an actual divide-by-2-and-get-remainder operation rather than simply a boolean 'and' operation to extract the least-significant bit. If so, the speed difference is likely to be very minimal, but it still might be worth profiling things to check. Also, `c /= 2` could be written as `c >>>= 1`.

Comment: By the way, since this is a code review question, I would suggest a comment pointing the reader to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_rabin or some such page explaining where the list `{ 2, 7, 61 }` comes from, and what the limitations are on your input.

Comment: @ToddLehman I'm sure Java optimizes the division by 2 even for signed operands, [but it's slower](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617265/581205). Together with the zero test it could be optimized without the adjustment, but I don't know i it happens.

Comment: When i try to run the code, `isPrime()` doesnt work for `long`. Does anybody have same problem?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for numbers less than 10 million (you are only going up to 100 million).

I think that  checking the low bit `(num & 1) == 0` is quicker than checking the remainder `num % 2 == 0`.  Similarly, bit shifting is quicker for division or multiplication by 2: `d /= 2` could be `d >> 1`.

You might experiment with doing an initial check for division by a few low primes (3, 5, 7, 11) in your IsPrime method and see if that makes a difference.

Finally, for your "random" numbers, you might want to choose products of primes, e.g. 3*5*7*11*13..., or maybe that plus 1.  Maybe that's crazy.  But some "random" numbers might provide richer test cases than others, and cause a faster elimination of non-primes.

Answer (score 3):

Java already has [`BigInteger.isProbablePrime(int certainty)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime(int)) and [`BigInteger.nextProbablePrime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#nextProbablePrime()).  (There is no method to get the previous probable prime, though, so you'll need to get creative.)

That said, your Miller-Rabin implementation works remarkably quickly and accurately.  Testing numbers up to 100 million, I found that it is 100% accurate in that range.  To achieve 100% accuracy in that range with `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()`, you would need a `certainty` parameter of at least 9.

To obtain a list of primes within a range, you would be better off with the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  For comparison, I tried generating a list of primes up to 100 million with three methods:

- Sieve of Eratosthenes (using [@JavaDeveloper's implementation with bugfixes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45152/9357)): 3 seconds
- Your `primes()` function: 37 seconds
- Testing `BigInteger.valueOf(i).isProbablePrime(9)` for `i` up to 100 million: ≈ 4 minutes

Comment: It's [provably 100% accurate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants_of_the_test) for numbers below 4,759,123,141. But sadly (**as nobody noticed**) it's totally broken for big numbers due to overflow.

Answer (score 3):

In your `millerRabin()` function, the calculation of `s` and `d` can be factored out of the loop, as they only depend on `n`, not `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Several improvements: Consider that the test "if (p % 3 == 0)..." will identify 33.3% of all numbers as composite. If Miller-Rabin takes longer than three times to test whether p % 3 == 0, adding that test makes the code run faster on average. Same obviously with p % 5 == 0 and so on. You should probably check directly at least up to 100 or so.

For a 32 bit number, you'll do about 32 squaring operations modulo p. However, you can probably do at least four by just accessing a table. For example, when a = 2 any power up to 31 can be taken from a table. That saves probably 10% or more of the work.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly nobody noticed that the whole computation is broken for big numbers due to overflow in

```
private static long modpow(long x, long c, long m) {
    ...
    result = (result * aktpot) % m;
    ...
}
```

and

```
private static boolean millerRabin(long n) {
    ...
    x = (x * x) % n;
    ...
}
```

I'd suggest changing the signature of

```
public static boolean IsPrime(long num)
```

to accept `int` only. And obviously changing the name to `isPrime`.

Answer (score 0):

- `if i<2` (one test <) is better than is `if i<=1` (= test and < test)
- change  `String ans="";` in  `StringBuilder ans=new StringBuilder();`
- change `for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){` in   `for (int i=0,n=arr.length;i<n;i++){`
- read Joshua Blosh "Effective Java" book

Comment: "`if i<2` (one test `<`) is better than is `if i<=1` (`=` test and `<` test)" AFAIK this is completely false. `<=` does **not** need to perform two comparisons, it will simply call a different conditional jump instruction at the machine level, which uses a *slightly* different circuit which takes *exactly* the same time to perform the comparison(keep in mind that if the difference in timing is too small then it's like if it were 0 since pipelines compute in steps of `clock_time/pipeline_steps` seconds.

Comment: @Bakuriu ok! (I've not look how my Java's compiler do with <=) I was told about this optimization with Sybase requester.

Comment: Forget about points 1 and 3. These are valid just for dumb compilers, Java can optimize such low level stuff itself.